# How to convert leds from AA batteries to a DC source

Tags: power, 12v, conversion

I have 2 strings of 100 white LEDs each that are powered by a battery pack of 3 AA batteries for each string. What I would like to do is use one of my low voltage power supplies that are typically used for landscape lighting and get rid of the batteries. The power supply outputs 12v with a maximum of 200w. Is this feasible to use as a power source and if so what would be needed to run them off the power supply at the correct voltage and amperage? If there are other suggestions for powering the lights, I'm open to them. I just want to get rid of dealing with replacing batteries on the regular. For reference, the lights go in a cabana that we sit in most evenings so we would go through quite a few. Any help would be appreciated.

Update - 6-27-2021  First, thanks to everyone for giving me some great direction. To clarify, the three batteries are run in series and it has a IC board that is the on/off switch. Position 0 is off, position 1 is flashing LED and position 2 is on constant. The flashing is seizure inducing and I would NEVER use this.

Sounds like I could also use a powered USB hub with 5v to power the strings. I have one that has 4 ports so this might be the other option.

Again, thank you for the help!

Comment: If I am not mistaken the 12V for the lights is AC and a buck converter and linear regulators need DC. There needs to be a AC to DC conversion. My recommendation is use a small wall wart. A simple diode and resistor may be all you need but without more detail it is just a guess

Comment: Some landscape lighting is AC. Some is DC. Led tech has pushed the DC version in some areas.

Comment: Fun fact: a converter designed for AC input can also work on DC.

Answer (score 4):

3 AA batteries is roughly 4.5V, up to 5.1V when fresh. LED strands using this supply are perfectly ok to convert to a 5V supply. They also use only a couple hundred mA.

Taken together, this means that your 100-light strand (3-battery, 4.5V) is well within what a USB-capable supply can deliver.

And I've done this conversion many times, taking inexpensive 3-AA powered LED strands/ropes and converted them to use a USB powerbank supply, providing many hours of run-time for camping and at music festivals.

I'm certain your 100-LED strand is the same, it will run on USB 5V.

Anyway, assuming your low-voltage lighting power is from a transformer, it'll be 12V AC, a common voltage for consumer stuff (commercial sometimes uses 24V.) To use that voltage you'll need get a 12V AC to 5V adapter. Find one suitable for USB, either 1A or 2A, which will work perfectly with the LEDs. Yes, these exist, they're popular and common.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if it's 12V AC or DC.

If AC, you need to rectify it to DC. Using four 1n400x diodes as a diode bridge rectifier, is a very simple way of doing it. Now that we have DC, you need to regulate it down to the 4.5V the light's controller pack wants. You could build a regulator and make all sorts of measurements but let's do the practical thing. The led string isn't high current and it's not particularly sensitive. You have 12V DC or if rectified probably 10.6V. You know what works great at regulating that down to 5V? A run of the mill car usb charger. Use a car usb charger after the diode bridge. Try to find a 2A one as those are almost always semi decent switching regulators. 5 bucks. Avoid the ones that say 1A or 750 mA.

Now you have 5V out. That's almost what the led packs want. You could live life on the edge and just apply that to the led string battery connections. You risk the life of the packs by a bit by doing that. Or you can play it safe and use an extra 1n400x diode to drop that down by another ~0.7V giving the led pack ~4.3V. No modification needed to the regulator car usb charger or the led string pack.

Comment: don't use a car USB charger after the diode bridge, that's silly. You can use a normal USB charger and plug it into whatever the 12V power supply is plugged into. (Unless it's something unusual like a boat battery)

Comment: @user253751 a "normal usb charger" typically means a wall wart 120V AC to 5V DC regulator. A "car usb charger" is a 12V DC to 5V DC regulator. How is it silly? Oh because you don't understand that a landscaping low voltage system probably already has a long cable run so OP doesn't need to run extra cables to a remote location?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on some details..

1. Does the AA power pack that powers the LED strip just contain batteries, and no circuitry and then directly connects to the strips (presumably there may be some resistors or minimal circuitry in the strip).
2. Are the AA batteries in series or parallel?

If the AA batteries are in series then you have 4.5V from the battery pack, this is most likely the case, but its important to verify this. At that point all you really need to do to replace the batteries is to provide a power source of the same voltage and sufficient amperage. The current isnt likely to be super high if its powered off just 3 AA batteries. In series they can supply about at most 50mA current continuous. So any reasonable power supply will handle that.

If you want to power it off of a 12V supply then what you do depends on if its AC or DC.

For a DC power supply:

You need to step the voltage down to 4.5V presuming the AA are in series. Make sure your 12V supply is DC. To do that I'd recommend a step-down DC-DC converter, just make sure it works within the voltage range needed. Here is one such example of a converter:

[https://www.amazon.com/FULARR-Converter-Step-Down-Regulator-Adjustable/dp/B07THSDWHX/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=DC-DC+converter+4.5v&qid=1624671048&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07THSDWHX)

You can of course solder up your own from scratch as well. The nice thing about an adjustable one is if it turns out those batteries were in parallel you can just adjust the voltage to 1.5V (I doubt this though).

For an AC supply:

In this case you would want a transformer that can convert 12V AC to 5V/4.5V AC, then a rectifier, then a a nice big capacitor to smooth it all out. That should give you the output voltage you need from AC. Though it wont be all that well regulated, it will work, but personally I would probably convert it to DC without stepping it down to 5V and then it would act as a 12V DC supply at which point you can add the DC-DC converter described above. By doing it this way, rather than a transformer, you will get a nice clean 4.5V DC output that wont swing when your input voltage swings. Probably overkill, so if your supply is AC go whichever route make sense.

Of course the simpler answer is just get yourself a 5V DC power supply and call it a day. These lights are so low power almost any supply should do and will cost you dollars at most. The 200W supply your providing is certainly overkill.

Otherwise you should be good to go. Just check the voltages are what is expected and if there is some sort of circuit you didnt describe please update your question.

Answer (score -2):

If you connect the two strings in series then they will require a 9V supply.  You could find a switch mode buck converter (most efficient) or linear regulator (simplest) or a string of diodes (1N4001 etc will drop a little under 1V each so 3 or 4 would do) - this is a little better than using a resistor since the voltage drop is  less sensitive to the current, which we don’t know.

Comment: As per other comments, it’s possible your 12V is AC.  Using a string of diodes could still be a valid solution, although the flicker may be unacceptable since you would effectively have half wave rectification.